# Forecasting with BSTS and external predictors

Tags: time-series, forecasting, bsts

Can I use bsts with external predictors such as promotions, holidays etc? How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can if you correctly pre-specify the lead and lag structures around each holiday. Also care needs to be taken to properly specify and level shifts or trnd changes that may have occurred. Also you need to make sure that there are no anomalies ( 1 time pulses) in your data. Also you need to specify if all of the data should be used or just a recent portion reflecting transience in the model parameters. You also need to be concerned with any non-constant error variance is lurking and needs to be remedied. Additionally there may be some ARIMA structure that may be necessary to render a final set of model residuals to be free of structure .. always a good idea. Finally if there are particular days or weeks in the month or months in the year that are consistently different then appropriate dummy variables need to be pre-specified.

Finally there may be pre-promotion response that might need to be identified and incorporated to reflect assignable cause.

Finally the way you identify pre and post effects around each holiday is to either spend a lot of time looking at graphs or use a sophisticated search engine to effectively suggest this via a form of AI.

Comment: So in your opinion, does bsts provide a better time series forecast (both in terms of accuracy and robustness) versus exponential smoothing?

Comment: I would think so as it is more general .

Comment: That comes with the caveat that we would need to fill in *all* the parameters you mentioned above, and many more, correctly? Which is a tough task on its own.

Comment: or preferably do a stepdown and only use the statistically significant parameters

Comment: I am not sure I followed now. What do you mean with a stepdown? Even with such parameters, I am concerned about prediction accuracy vs exponential smoothing.

Comment: Stepdown is when you delete insigificant parameters from a model and just retain the statistically significant ones.

Comment: Well, identifying those *insignificant* one does not even require BSTS though. Or two different methods (e.g. regression vs BSTS) would give different sets of insignificant parameters, assuming we keep the same target variables?